# How do I backup a SQL Server 2012 database using SMO

Tags: c#, sql, smo, sql-server-2012

I have some code that uses the SQL Server 2005 SMO objects to backup and restore SQL Server databases this is working fine but I have been tasked with updating the code to work with SQL Server 2012 databases.

I understand I need to use the latest SQL Server 2012 SDK to do this up the backup and restore methods are no longer there.

Have these methods been deprecated and should I just write SQL script to do the same thing instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know they are still there. Are you sure you've got the right download? Also they've twiddled with what is in what dll, and namespaces.

We just got rid of DMO, and just issue back up and restore commands instead. Had to write a bit more code, but not that much more. Only thing we were using DMO for was feedback for a progress bar, just swapped that for an animation.
PS have you tried your SMO code. DMO with backwards compatibility pack still works with 2012, though it's not meant to.

Comment: Thanks I didnt realise they had moved to the Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll. like you if it wasn't for the progress changed events I could I of used used SQL script instead.

Comment: Our customer's dbs aren't that big, so we dispensed with the feed back. Our Customer facing Backup/restore tool is Win32 so SMO wasn't an option without a near total rewrite anyway, so that was another simplification of the scope. I learnt something as well, so you are welcome.